# team foundation server 2013 TF30172

Tags: tfs

We are testing out the TFS 2013 preview and we get the error TF30172 when we try and create new team projects from VS 2012.   The error goes away after we install the VS 2013 preview.  Are there any workaround for VS 2012

Comment: For Team Project Creation, you need to match the version of the TFS client tools to the version of the TFS server.  However, once you've created a team project, you can use it from any supported version.